# Why PYQT5 connecting multiple checkboxes does not work in a loop, but works by writing out everything manually

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am working on PyQT5 and I have the following list.

```
self.config_cbs = [self.gui.cb_config_0, \
                   self.gui.cb_config_1, \
                   self.gui.cb_config_2, \
                   self.gui.cb_config_3, \
                   self.gui.cb_config_4, \
                   self.gui.cb_config_5, \
                   self.gui.cb_config_6, \
                   self.gui.cb_config_7, \
                   self.gui.cb_config_8, \
                   self.gui.cb_config_9, \
                   self.gui.cb_config_10, \
                   self.gui.cb_config_11]
```

I want to connect all checkboxes to the same function.

Does anyone know, why does this NOT work?

```
for i, cb in enumerate(self.config_cbs):
      cb.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.config_cb_state_changed(i))
```

But this does work:

```
self.gui.cb_config_0.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.config_cb_state_changed(0))
self.gui.cb_config_1.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.config_cb_state_changed(1))
self.gui.cb_config_2.stateChanged.connect(lambda: self.config_cb_state_changed(2))
...
```

Aren't these two equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>**Solution 1**</del>

Can you try with this?

```
for i, cb in enumerate(self.config_cbs):
    cb.stateChanged.connect(lambda i=i: self.config_cb_state_changed(i))
```

**Solution 2**

If it still does not work, you can still alter your function `config_cb_state_changed()` and identify the checkbox which triggered the signal with `self.sender()` (I assume all the code is part of the same class).

```
...
for cb in self.config_cbs:
    cb.stateChanged.connect(self.config_cb_state_changed)
...

def config_cb_state_changed(state: bool):
    cb = self.sender()
    # If needed, you can find your index i
    i = self.config_cbs.index(cb)
    # And just to be sure...
    assert isinstance(cb, QCheckBox)
    assert cb.isChecked() == state
```

**Solution 1 edited**

```
for i, cb in enumerate(self.config_cbs):
    cb.stateChanged.connect(lambda state, i=i: self.config_cb_state_changed(i))
```

Comment: The first solution did not work, the second did work, however I find it weird that I even have to do that.... Thank you anyway...

Comment: You did not mention the problem. I guess: whichever checkbox you click, you get `i=11` (the last added)?

Comment: See this (it refers to PyQt4 but the problem is the same): https://python.tutorialink.com/connecting-slots-and-signals-in-pyqt4-in-a-loop/

Comment: yes, that is correct

Comment: Can you try the solution 1 I edited in my first message?